# Is it possible to drag and drop events into a row with an existing event in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm currently working a hotel booking using fullcalendar and it seems that full calendar can't drop events into a row that has existing events( that's what I've learn so far ).But if there are ways to do it, then please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have tried anything then paste it above or this question will be flagged as not a programming question.

Comment: "it seems that full calendar can't drop events into a row that has existing events". What makes you think that? Try it at https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/demos/external-dragging.html . By default you can put events wherever you like, including on top of each other. If you've got some code of your own that isn't working as you expect, please post it here and maybe we can try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

eventOverlap: true //
Allow you to drop more than one event in the period.

selectOverlap: true 
//Allow you to select over other event.